# Launch an unparented process from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, process

By default, when you launch a process from PowerShell, it is attached to its parent (the shell). If you kill the process tree, these processes also die. I would like to launch a process that is a peer to the shell; aka. when I kill the PowerShell tree, I don't want it to die.

```
$spotifyProcess = start Spotify.exe -PassThru

$spotifyParentId = (gwmi win32_process -Filter "processid='$($spotifyProcess.Id)'").ParentProcessId
$shellId = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().Id

if ($spotifyParentId -eq $shellId)
{
    throw 'Not what I want!!'
}
```

Comment: `Invoke-CimMethod Win32_Process @{CommandLine='notepad'} Create`

Comment: Or double-hop it: `powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process Spotify.exe"` from within powershell - the "inner" powershell.exe exits as soon as Start-Process returns, so notepad.exe is no longer part of the same process tree as your "outer" powershell.exe process

Comment: Both of these work. The `powershell.exe` one is simpler... would you mind turning it into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "classic" trick, due to the simple nature of a Process Tree in Windows (just a backwards linked list to each process' ancestor), is to open a separate process that then in turn launches your new "independent" process.

In `powershell.exe` this is super easy:

```
powershell.exe -Command 'Start-Process notepad.exe'
```

The "inner" `powershell.exe` instance launches `notepad.exe`, and exits immediately, leaving `notepad.exe` orphaned

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa389388.aspx) method of `Win32_Process` WMI class. There are several ways to call it in PowerShell:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList notepad

([WmiClass]'Win32_Process').Create('notepad')
```

**v3+:**

```
Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName Win32_Process -MethodName Create -Arguments @{CommandLine='notepad'}
```

Comment: This is the only way that worked for me when trying to launch a long-running background process from a Zabbix agent UserParameter script